# DownloadStringAsync doesn't work for a Github URL in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, url, https, download

I can use `DownloadStringAsync` to grab some URLs but not others

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com:443/krisives/GRemote/master/VERSION.txt");

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        String version = e.Result.Trim();
        Console.WriteLine(version);
        if (version != GRemoteDialog.Version)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Version " + version + " is available!");
        }
    }
```

If you change the URL to `google.com` it will work. How can I get this to
work for Github.com or why is it failing?

Thanks!

Comment: My example code is happening in a GUI thread/response to click, so I don't have to add a Console.ReadLine() right ?

Comment: Source file is here last two methods: https://github.com/krisives/GRemote/blob/master/Remote/GRemoteDialog.cs

Comment: Does it time out? Exit immediately? Throw an exception? Please provide more info on how it fails *for you*.

Comment: Sorry, it does nothing at all. If there is a timeout it's longer than I've waited while testing.